# How can I create a plot with point with interpolation for each individual

Tags: r

Here is my df:

```
            id power percent_power    relVO2
1  AC12-PRD-C1    25      21.73913  8.797619
2  AC12-PRD-C1    40      34.78261  9.758929
3  AC12-PRD-C1    55      47.82609 11.324405
4  AC12-PRD-C1    70      60.86957 12.800595
5  AC12-PRD-C1    85      73.91304 14.273810
6  AC12-PRD-C1   100      86.95652 16.020833
7  AC12-PRD-C1   115     100.00000 17.830357
8  AL13-PRD-C1    25      19.23077  7.733918
9  AL13-PRD-C1    40      30.76923  8.754386
10 AL13-PRD-C1    55      42.30769 10.000000
11 AL13-PRD-C1    70      53.84615 11.514620
12 AL13-PRD-C1    85      65.38462 13.444444
13 AL13-PRD-C1   100      76.92308 15.748538
14 AL13-PRD-C1   115      88.46154 16.970760
15 AL13-PRD-C1   130     100.00000 18.695906
16 BM06-PRD-S1    25      25.00000 10.094108
17 BM06-PRD-S1    40      40.00000 11.734861
18 BM06-PRD-S1    55      55.00000 14.120295
19 BM06-PRD-S1    70      70.00000 16.133388
20 BM06-PRD-S1    85      85.00000 18.494272
21 BM06-PRD-S1   100     100.00000 20.654664
22 CB19-PRD-S1    25      13.15789 12.621429
23 CB19-PRD-S1    40      21.05263 13.510714
24 CB19-PRD-S1    55      28.94737 15.446429
25 CB19-PRD-S1    70      36.84211 17.771429
26 CB19-PRD-S1    85      44.73684 18.639286
27 CB19-PRD-S1   100      52.63158 21.050000
28 CB19-PRD-S1   115      60.52632 23.985714
29 CB19-PRD-S1   130      68.42105 25.582143
30 CB19-PRD-S1   145      76.31579 28.000000
31 CB19-PRD-S1   160      84.21053 29.150000
32 CB19-PRD-S1   175      92.10526 33.489286
33 CB19-PRD-S1   190     100.00000 34.907143
34 CC14-PRD-S1    20      22.22222  9.634146
35 CC14-PRD-S1    30      33.33333 10.747967
36 CC14-PRD-S1    40      44.44444 12.089431
37 CC14-PRD-S1    50      55.55556 14.288618
38 CC14-PRD-S1    60      66.66667 15.341463
39 CC14-PRD-S1    70      77.77778 16.207317
40 CC14-PRD-S1    80      88.88889 18.117886
41 CC14-PRD-S1    90     100.00000 19.556911
42 DA03-PRD-C1    20      15.38462  8.047826
43 DA03-PRD-C1    30      23.07692  8.950000
44 DA03-PRD-C1    40      30.76923  9.710870
45 DA03-PRD-C1    50      38.46154 10.410870
46 DA03-PRD-C1    60      46.15385 10.850000
47 DA03-PRD-C1    70      53.84615 12.402174
48 DA03-PRD-C1    80      61.53846 13.410870
49 DA03-PRD-C1    90      69.23077 13.863043
50 DA03-PRD-C1   100      76.92308 14.754348
```

I know how to create a `geom_smooth` and `geom_line` with `x=percentPPO`, and `y=relVO2`, but I would like to create a point plot (`geom_point`?) for every x value (lets say every 5 % of `percentPPO`) where the point are either connected or not.

Some participants don't have the 5% increment, so it has to be interpolated between the nearest lower value and the nearest higher value for each of them, and then get a mean value for every 5%.

This should look like this:

[image]

Thank you very much everyone,

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: How you tried anything yet? Where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: I don't think there's a ggplot option to do a geom smooth but plot points not lines. But you can do the same process directly: fit a simple model (loess, gam, whatever) and `predict` for each point. You may want to use `tidyr::complete` to create all the placeholder rows for `id` and whichever variable is on your x-axis.

Comment: What I have done so far is a `lm` model with points for each individual.

Comment: Thanks Gregor. I don't know how to proceed what you have suggested unfortunately.